# asp: access html element inside repeateritem itemtemplate from codebehind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asprepeater

How to access HTML "input type="checkbox" data-item="myItems" id="id123"" in ascx.cs file when the input is in asp:repeater ?
This does not work, cuz findcontrol only works with system.web.ui.control:

```
var checkBox = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("id123");
```

This:

```
var checkBox = (Checkbox)e.Item.FindControl("id123");
```

will work if I make asp:checkbox instead html input. 
But then another question: What is  the equivalent for html input "data-" attribute in asp:checkbox ?

Comment: do you have runat="server" set on html input tag?

Answer (score 2):

*Answer to first part*:

You need to set `runat="server"` on the html input.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id123" data-item="myItems" runat="server".....
```

*Answer to second part*:

You can specify any attribute on server controls and they will be spewed as is in the generated html. So you can have:

```
<asp:checkbox id="id123" data-item="myItems" runat="server"....
```

Comment: Good point. Marek, also pay no mind to the "warnings" Visual Studio gives you regarding "invalid attributes" on those controls. They will still show properly. You can test this most easily using a asp:textbox with placeholder text.

Comment: @Lopsided Thanks for pointing out the 'warning' warning :) I just noticed, you beat me to the answer first. +1 for that on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include the `runat="server"` attribute in any element that you want to access from the code-behind.